# OCaml - What is an unsound type?

Tags: ocaml

> Recently I was given the code
>
> ```
> List.fold_left (fun acc x -> raise x ; acc) 3
> ```
>
> I'm completely fine with this partial application having a functional
>   value of type `exn list -> int`, and the fact it yields a warning
>   isn't surprising. I am, however, not certain what half of the warning
>   means:
>
> ```
> Warning 21: this statement never returns (or has an unsound type.)
> ```
>
> I can't actually find any reference to this warning where it isn't the
>   result of a non-returning statement. Even the man page for ocamlc only
>   mentions non-returning statements for this warning, and warnings.ml
>   refers to it merely as `Nonreturning_statement`.
>
> I am familiar with the concept of soundness as it relates to type
>   systems, but the idea of a type itself being inherently unsound seems
>   odd to me.
>
> So my questions are:
>
> What exactly is an unsound type?
>
> What's a situation in which an unsound type would arise when OCaml
>   would only issue a warning rather than failing hard outright?

Someone has posted this question, and while I was writing an answer, it was deleted.  I believe the question is very interesting and worth for reposting.  Please consider you may have someone who is willing to help you :-(

Comment: I believe the question was removed because it was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278561/avoid-the-warning-warning-21-this-statement-never-returns-or-has-an-unsound-t, where the warning was caused by the use of an external (js_of_ocaml) function with unconstrained result type – as in your answer below. I suspect the questioner is the one who just gave me a +1 on the accepted answer. Granted, the focus there is a little different.

Comment: I was the person who asked/deleted that; I only just spotted (hehe) this. What @antron said is precisely why I deleted it. And yes, that +1 was from me. ;)

Answer (score 14):

## How Warning 21 is reported

First, let's think of functions which returns unrelated `'a`: I do not mean function like `let id x = x` here since it has type `'a -> 'a` and the return type `'a` relates with the input.  I mean functions like `raise : exn -> 'a` and `exit : int -> 'a`.

These functions return unrelated `'a` are considered never returning.  Since the type `'a` (more precisely `forall 'a. 'a`) has no citizen.  Only thing the functions can do are terminating the program (exit or raising an exception) or falling into an infinite loop: `let rec loop () = loop ()`.

Warning 21 is mentioned when the type of a statement is `'a`.  (Actually there is another condition but I just skip for simplicity.)  For example,

```
# loop (); print_string "end of the infinite loop";;
Warning 21: this statement never returns (or has an unsound type.)
```

This is the main purpose of warning 21.  Then what is the latter half?

## "Unsound type"

Warning 21 can be reported even if the statement *returns* something actually.  In this case, as the warning message suggests the statement has a unsound type.

Why unsound?  Since the expression does return a value of type `forall 'a. 'a`, which has no citizen.  It breaks the basis of the type theory OCaml depends on.

In OCaml, there *are* several ways to write an expression with such an unsound type:

Use of `Obj.magic`.  It screws type system therefore you can write an expression of type `'a` which returns:

```
(Obj.magic 1); print_string "2"
```

Use of `external`.  Same as `Obj.magic` you can give arbitrary type to any external values and functions:

```
external crazy : unit -> 'a = "%identity"
let f () = crazy ()  (* val f : unit -> 'a *)
let _ = f (); print_string "3"
```

For OCaml type system, it is impossible to distinguish non-returning expressions and expressions with unsound types.  This is why it cannot rule out unsound things as errors. Tracking the definitions to tell a statement has an unsound type or not is generally impossible either and costs a lot even when possible.

Comment: Nice answer. For the sake of completeness, you might want to mention demarshalling (`input_value` and `Marshal.from_*`) as unsound functions. (in fact I'd argue that they're more useful than `Obj.magic`, especially for someone who's not an expert in type systems).