# Does a non terminating function have a type?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Consider for example `let f x = f x in f 1`. Is its signature defined?
If so, what is it?
One could argue, that OCaml doesn't know about the fact that it's not terminating and that its type is simply inferred as `'a`. Is that correct?

```
let a b = let rec f x = f x in f 1;;
```

is for example `val a : 'a -> 'b` eventhough it is very clear, that when `a` is applied, there won't be a `'b`

Comment: The way I look at it, your `a` has the type you say. So it has a type. But this is not the type of any function that returns normally. Note that it is also the type of `let f x = raise Not_found`

Comment: In general I would have said `val a : 'a -> Void`, but Ocaml doesn't seem to have a void type.

Comment: Non-termination has no effect on the type (and it would open a huge can of undecidable worms). Your first example can be simplified to `let rec f x = f 1`, which has type `int -> 'a`.

Comment: See also: [OCaml - What is an unsound type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428933/ocaml-what-is-an-unsound-type)

Answer (score 1):

Then requirement for a sound type system when you have `type(E) = T` is that *if* `E` evaluates to some value `v`, then  `v` is a value that belongs to type `T`. A type is meaningful when the expression gives a value, and exceptions and infinite loops do not.

The type checker however is total, and gives a type for all expression, even if it is just a free type variable.

Here the return type is left unbound, and is printed as `'a`.

```
# let f x = if x then (failwith "A") else (failwith "B");;
val f : bool -> 'a = <fun>
```

Here the return type of the `then` branch is unified with the type of the `else` branch:

```
# let f x = if x then (failwith "A") else 5;;
val f : bool -> int = <fun>
#
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to read function types like `unit -> 'a` is to remember that the
type variable `'a` encompasses empty types.

For example, if I have a function `f`

```
let rec f:'a. _ -> 'a = fun () -> f ()
```

and an empty type

```
type empty = |
(* using 4.07 empty variants *)
(* or *)
type (_,_) eq = Refl: ('a,'a) eq
type empty = (float,int) eq
```

then I can restrict the type of f to `unit -> empty`:

```
 let g: unit -> empty = f
```

Moreover, the more general type of `f` can be useful in presence of branches.
For instance, I could define a `return` that raises an exception in order
to exit early from a for-loop:

```
let search pred n =
  let exception Return of int in
  let return: 'a. int -> 'a = fun n -> raise (Return n) in
  try
    for i = 0 to n do
      if pred i then return i
    done;
    None
 with Return n -> Some n
```

Here, the polymorphic type of `return` makes it possible to use it in a context
where `unit` was expected.